# fit() using custom fittype() returns specified startpoint values

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

While using the `fit` function in matlab, it is returning the start values I specified in the code.

So say in the `fit` function arguments I give `fit(... 'start', [2.9 10000] ...)`, the return values would be

```
... = 2.9 (some 95% confidence value)

... = 10000 (some 95% confidence value)
```

Why is matlab not tuning the fit parameters here? I tried changing the start points around, but it still just returns the values that I enter in. I also plotted the function (with the parameters equal to the start points I entered) against the data I'm fitting to and they are very close to each other.

Am I using the fit function wrong? Is there any way that I can get exact fit parameters from matlab?

Also, just as a side note, but is it possible to get something (such as a `R^2` value) that characterized how well the fit is?

Thanks!

Edit: 
Here is what I have for the fit function:

myfitopt = fitoptions('Method', 'NonlinearLeastSquares', 'start', [13.5*10^3, 1.31*10^4]); % options

myfittype = fittype('4*k*Temp*beta/(m*((2*pi)^4*(f^2-v_0^2)^2+(2*pi*f*beta)^2))', 'independent', 'f', 'problem', {'k', 'm', 'Temp'}, 'coefficients', {'beta', 'v_0'}, 'options', myfitopt)

myfit = fit(freq', p, myfittype, 'problem', {k_B, mass, Temperature}) % play around with the start value of beta and v_0

this is returning:

myfittype =

```
 General model:
 myfittype(beta,v_0,k,m,Temp,f) = 4*k*Temp*beta/(m*((2*pi)^4*(f^2-v_0^2)^2+
                (2*pi*f*beta)^2))
```

myfit =

```
 General model:
 myfit(f) = 4*k*Temp*beta/(m*((2*pi)^4*(f^2-v_0^2)^2+(2*pi*f*beta)^2))
 Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
   beta =    1.35e+04  (-4.909e+09, 4.909e+09)
   v_0 =    1.31e+04  (-3.802e+08, 3.802e+08)
 Problem parameters:
   k =   1.381e-23
   m =   1.176e-12
   Temp =       295.5
```

where beta and v_0 are just what I entered as start values with really big error range. Why is the code not changing these coefficients around to fit it to the data?

Thank you!

Comment: Your question needs more details. What is the model you are using inside the 'fit' function? How is the shape of the data, can you post a plot in the question?

Answer (score 1):

With the little information you have provided, it is very hard to give you a certain solution. However, I explain the fitting process in the simplest way possible.

When dealing with curve/surface fitting you should consider 3 important steps:

**1. select a model**

for instance for the following data selecting a `poly2` model is proper.
[image]

However you can have different choices for the type, such as :

```
poly1   Y = p1*x+p2
poly2   Y = p1*x^2+p2*x+p3
poly3   Y = p1*x^3+p2*x^2+...+p4
...etc., up to poly9    Y = p1*x^9+p2*x^8+...+p10
```

Check every other details [here](http://it.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/list-of-library-models-for-curve-and-surface-fitting.html#btbcvnl).

**2. fit the model to the data**

Here you can use `fit` function to produce a fit object, `f`.

```
f = fit(x,y,'poly2')
```

The result can be as follows:

```
f = 

     Linear model Poly2:
     f(x) = p1*x^2 + p2*x + p3
     Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
       p1 =    0.006541  (0.006124, 0.006958)
       p2 =      -23.51  (-25.09, -21.93)
       p3 =   2.113e+04  (1.964e+04, 2.262e+04)
```

This shows the model together with the coefficients that the fit function has found for you.

**3. Now you can use the model, easily:**

```
f(1900)
ans =
       74.5558
```

Which is the red point on the plot:
[image]

Many other properties of the `fit` function can be modified using `fitoptions` function. Check matlab documentations on `fit` and `fitoptions` [here](http://it.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fit.html).

The `startpoint` property specifies the coefficient starting values. In order to use `startpoint` options, you may use `fitoption` , then make the `fittype` and then use `fit` as follows:

```
fo = fitoptions('Method','NonlinearLeastSquares','Lower',[0,0],'Upper', Inf,max(cdate)],'StartPoint',[1 1]);
ft = fittype('a*(x-b)^n','problem','n','options',fo);
[curve2,gof2] = fit(xdata,ydata,ft,'problem',2)
```

**To answer you side note**

You could use [residual analysis](http://it.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/residual-analysis.html) to check the quality of the fit.